# Toggleing opacity with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, opacity

I have been working on this gallery-like menu, I pretty much have an ordered list and 15 images. The images are all `opacity: 0` ecept for the first one. When I click on the first image, the rest should fade in to `opacity: 1`.

Here is my html:

```
<ol id="gallery">
  <li><img id="first_img" src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss1_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss2_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss3_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss4_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss5_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss6_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss7_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss8_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss9_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss10_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss11_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss12_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss13_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss14_tmb.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.astro-galaxy.com/screens/ss15_tmb.jpg"></li>
</ol>
```

And here my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("first-img").click(function() {
    $("#gallery img").animate({"opacity": "toggle"});
  });
});
```

I've been hours looking at posts to see a solution, with no luck, please help.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us what behavior you're currently seeing, not just what you want.

Comment: correct your jquery selector instead of `first-img` it should be `#first-img`

Comment: When I finished correcting everything, and I clicked the image, the image disapeared instead of the rest of them apearing. But I got what I was looking for @JRulle found the solution, I'm still wandering, could I get them to apear in order, like first the first one, then second one, and so forth to the last one apearing, and same effect backwards when I click again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to adjust your JavaScript a bit to handle the toggle in an if statement. also, your first-image selector should be #first_image to match the id in your HTML. [**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wfyvenh/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first_img").click(function() {
    if($("#gallery img").not("#first_img").css("opacity") == 0) {
      $("#gallery img").not("#first_img").animate({opacity: "1"},1000);
    } else {
      $("#gallery img").not("#first_img").animate({opacity: "0"},1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: im not sure why you're doing any of this. An `if` statement is not needed at all here

Comment: OK, this is a complicated code and everything, but your code works perfectly, I just have one question, is there a way of making them apear in the order? Or am I going to add a separate id for every `li` element? Thank you!

Comment: do you mean appear sequentially? (i.e. one after the other)

Comment: Yes, I don't know if I can do that without adding an id for every element, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your identifier is wrong, it should be:

```
$("#first_img").click(function() {
```

instead of

```
$("first-img")
```

Which doesn't identify an `id` or us an `_` And you can just set `opacity` to 1 instead of `toggle` unless you want them to fade in and out

You can use simple CSS to set the opacity on page load rather then try and use JS selectors to do this:

CSS:

```
img{
  opacity: 0;
}

#first_img{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$("#first_img").click(function() {
  $("#gallery img").animate({"opacity": "1"});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c11ws92z/)

Comment: @user284098 you must have added it wrong, perhaps you didnt wrap it in a `$(document).ready` function, as you can see from my fiddle it's working just fine.

Comment: Yes, they do change to `opacity: 1`, but it doesn't toggle, which is what I was trying to search for.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you had a class that reduced the opacity. That way you could use the toggleClass method as such:

```
$("first-img").click(function() {
  $("#gallery img).toggleClass("toggledImg");
}
```

Then add the custom class to your CSS:

```
.toggledImg {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("first-img").click(function() {
$("#gallery img").animate({opacity:"1"});
});
});
```

before you should add css:

```
#gallery img{ opacity:0}
```